# SQLAlchemy listen for attribute change in many-to-many relationship and change other attributes of initiator

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, crud

I'm new to the SQLAlchemy and I wrote a simple CRUD database layout like this: I have three tables, Customer, Product, and Template. The idea is this: Each customer can have a template of the products he usually orders. When I fetch a particular customer from the database, his template along with all the products should be fetched as well. So I have a one-to-one relationship (customer-template) and one many-to-many relationship (template-product). Now, a template should contain fields such as quantity of a particular product, along with its net, gross and tax values. I'd like to have a listener on the quantity column, such that when the quantity of a particular product is changed, other attributes I mentioned will be changed too. So the code I wrote is as follows (please, if you can, also verify whether all the relationships are written appropriately)

```
from sqlalchemy import event
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, exc, column_property, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm.query import Query as _Query
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, String, Boolean, ForeignKey, UniqueConstraint, create_engine, Numeric
from decimal import *

# decimal operations settings
getcontext().prec = 6
getcontext().rounding = ROUND_HALF_UP

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///test.db')
Base = declarative_base()

# Initalize the database if it is not already.
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

# Create a session to handle updates.
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

# customer has a one-to-one relationship with template, where customer is the parent
class Customer(Base):
    __tablename__ = "customers"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    alias = Column(String)
    firm_name = Column(String)
    last_name = Column(String)
    first_name = Column(String)
    tax_id = Column(String, nullable=False)
    address = Column(String)
    postal_code = Column(String)
    city = Column(String)
    payment = Column(Boolean)
    template = relationship("Template", uselist=False, back_populates="customer")

# product has many-to-many relationship with template, where template is the parent
class Product(Base):
    __tablename__ = "products"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    product_name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    symbol = Column(String)
    unit = Column(String, nullable=False)
    unit_net_price = Column(Numeric, nullable=False)
    vat_rate = Column(Numeric, nullable=False)
    per_month = Column(Boolean, nullable=False)

# association table for the products-template many-to-many relationship
association_table = Table('association', Base.metadata,
    Column('product_id', Integer, ForeignKey('product.id')),
    Column('template_id', Integer, ForeignKey('template.id'))
)

# template implements one-to-one relationship with customer and many-to-many relationship with product
class Template(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    customer_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("customer.id"))
    customer = relationship("Customer", back_populates="template")
    products = relationship("Product", secondary=association_table)
    quantity = Column(Numeric)
    net_val = Column(Numeric)
    tax_val = Column(Numeric)
    gross_val = Column(Numeric)

    # TODO: implement constructor
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.quantity = Decimal(0.0)
        self.net_val = Decimal(0.0)
        self.tax_val = Decimal(0.0)
        self.gross_val = Decimal(0.0)

@event.listens_for(Template.quantity, "set")
def quantity_listener(target, value, oldvalue, initiator):
    print(target)
    print(initiator)
    # target.net_val =
    # target.tax_val =
    # target.gross_val =
```

Now, I'm unsure how should I get a particular initiator and set its values, since `products` in `Template` table is a list (?)

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what exactly do you want to accomplish in `quantity_listener` ?

Comment: I'd like to multiply the quantity of the product by this particular product's net price, obtain tax and gross values and set them for this product as well as save them to the database, I don't know whether it's clear enough

Comment: No idea how to use connection in set, but if you listen for updates with `(Template, 'after_update')` then you will get a connection parameter in kwargs.

Comment: What do you mean by connection? Could you write an answer such that I could see what you mean?

Comment: sure, let me look into the docs.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably do it like this. It's hard to use Sqlalchemy orm in such cases as you can't access the `Session` object we all got used to use.

```
@event.listens_for(Template, "after_update")
def quantity_listener(mapper, connection, target):
    field = 'quantity'
    added, _, deleted = get_history(target, field)

    # added is a new values of the specified field
    # deleted is the old values
    # so we basically check if 'quantity' has changed
    # its a tuple btw

    if added and deleted and added[0] != deleted[0]:

        stmt = Template.update(). \
            values(Template.something=Template.something * Template.other_something). \
            where(Template.id == target.id)

        conn.execute(stmt)

        # here goes another updates for products or you can have another 
        # listener for them
```

There might be a better way to accomplish this. I can't debug this right now and I can't manage to get your examples working. Hope it helps.

Comment: How can I improve my code such that it works better overall? (you said you can't get it to work)

Comment: I got an exception because there's no `__tablename__` in products. For testing you could have a function that inserts dummy data. Then, if that works, it's easy to debug.

Comment: I meant in `Template`, not `Products`. Np.